# Json Error: Missing property name after reference operator

Tags: json, powershell

When I try to access the below JSON file from powershell it show the following error: `Missing property name after reference operator.` Here is my JSON file:

```
{
    "Vnet": {
        "Service": "VirtualNetwork",
        "Name": "vnetname",
        "ResourceGroupName": "RGname",
        "Location": "Southeast Asia",
        "Address_Prefix": "11.0.0.0/16",
        "No_of_subnets": "1",
        "Subnet": {
            "1": {
                "SubnetName":"sub1",
                "Address_Prefix":"11.0.1.0/24"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the simple powershell command

```
$file = (Get-Content "//filelocation" | Out-String) | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output $file.Vnet.Subnet.1.SubnetName
```

**Note:** I'm author of the JSON file and I can make any changes to it too if needed.

Comment: Well, the JSON is 100% valid.

Comment: Yeah,verified in JSON lint too.You have any idea about the error?and how to solve it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PowerShell seems to misinterpret the `1` as an index. Put it in quotes (to make clear it's a property name) and the code will work as you expect:

```
Write-Output $file.Vnet.Subnet.'1'.SubnetName
```

Comment: Happens with any `propertyname` that starts with a number. E.g. 30DayLogCount